# How to install Lucida AI in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, github

How can I install Lucida artificial intelligence in Ubuntu 16.04? Here is the github repository https://github.com/claritylab/lucida . And this is the original site of the project http://lucida.ai/ .

Oh most importantly, is Lucida the alternative of apple Siri?